# How to $ as a string in a python template and not as a variable?

Tags: python-3.x

`t1 = Template('rnote over $actor #MintCream \n <$triangle{scale=5}> \n end note')`

$triangle is treated as a variable but I want to use it as a symbol.  how is it done?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly, this should do the trick:

`t1 = Template(r'note over $actor #MintCream \n <$triangle{scale=5}> \n end note')`

For details on meaning of `r'`, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals)